# .Net Rest Web Service response has default Data Contract namespace rather than expected namespace

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xml-serialization, datacontract

Details:

Interface Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "test")]
TestType TestOperation();
```

Type Definition:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName = "Test", Namespace="http://test.net/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class TestType {
```

Actual Result:

```
<TestType xmlns=http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ …
```

Expected Result:

```
<Test xmlns= http://test.net/ …
```

Please advise.

Comment: The following link might be helpful ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service is using the `DataContractSerializer` to serialize the response and therefore requires the data contract namespace. In order to override that I would recommend applying the XmlSerialzeFormat Attribute to the operation as follows...

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "test")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
TestType TestOperation();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a WCF service, it uses [data contract serializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731072.aspx) by default. Try using [data contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) attributes to decorate your class instead:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Test", Namespace="http://test.net/")]
public partial class TestType {
```

Note: you'll also need to add `DataMember` attributes to each field or property that you want serialized.

Comment: Indeed, converting to DataContract attributes would fix the simple “Test” example above, but in our scenario, we have converted rather large XML schemas into C# classes.  As such, converting that many XMLSerializer attributes does not seem practical. Thanks.